# http header value safe characters

Tags: http, header

I have a method which encodes some key-value entries into an ASCII string with [Percent-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1).

The result value is expected to be used as a http header value.

With following entries

```
("English", "love")
("한국어", "사랑")
```

The method generates

```
%ED%95%9C%EA%B5%AD%EC%96%B4=%EC%82%AC%EB%9E%91&English=love
```

Which looks like

```
key=value(&key=value)*
```

1. Keys and values are encoded as [Percent-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)
2. Encoded key and value are concatenated with `=`.
3. Pairs of encoded key and values are concatenated with `&`.

My question is, Is this output string can be used as http header field-value?
Is there any problem or concern?

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long you use printable US-ASCII, there shouldn't be a problem.